# Are docker containers destroyed when machine is restarted?

Tags: docker

I was having a network issue, so I restarted my local machine, which also aborted my docker default VM. So I ran the below command to restart my virtualbox instance `docker-machine restart default`.

I previously had built containers on default, but I want to know, do I need to rebuild those same containers now that I restarted default, or can I just run docker-compose up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not destroyed. They are stopped though. You can check with

```
docker ps -a
```

This will show all containers, stopped and running. In order to start a container

```
docker start <container name or container id>
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`. When I restarted the machine, once it's running, should I be able to see my containers w that command?

Comment: is your Docker daemon running? Try `sudo service docker start`

Comment: It seems like I am having a certificate issue, unrelated to this question. thanks for your help